# Bullet behaving like soft hyphen

Tags: css, html, unicode, responsive-design

I want to create list of inline items, separated by bullets, but I want to hide all bullets on the end of line. Example:

> France • Germany • Greece
>
> Hungary • Iceland • Ireland

(As you can see, there's no bullet between Greece and Hungary).

Now, the problem is, I need this to work in any viewport width. The text should wrap naturally and bullets should appear only when they are not at the line break.

This is somehow similar to soft hyphen (&shy;) behaviour.

Is there any method to achieve this? Maybe some kind of unicode control character..?

Thanks!

Comment: Post us some working fiddle, this will help us to help you

Comment: @Kirk What is unclear about the question? How could he put a working fiddle, when he has no idea how to make it work?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Yes, it's a duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to write simple css code:

```
.someclass{
list-style:none;
}
```

add class in your

```
<ui>
<li class="someclass">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this will only remove the bullets..

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Display Progress</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var geoList = [
             { Country: "India", State: "Delhi" },
             { Country: "US", State: "Alabama" },
             { Country: "US", State: "Georgia" },
             { Country: "US", State: "Texas" },
             { Country: "US", State: "NewYork" }
             ];
            $('#LoadPage').append("<ul id='cList'></ul>");
            for (i = 0; i < geoList.length; i++) {
                $("#cList").append("<li>" +
                geoList[i].Country + "-" +
                geoList[i].State + "</li>");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>   
        <div id="LoadPage">
        </div>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```